# how to use ROS navigation stack with 4 wheeled robots

Tags: mobile-robot, ros, navigation, autonomous-car

I have a 4 wheeled toy car, with 5 motors, one on each wheel and one is used for steering. How can I use ROS navigation stack with this robot since navigation stack is used with differential drive robot?

Is their a way I can map cmd_vel(x,y and theta) of differential drive into my robot?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is. You need to develop or look for the developed equations of velocities that provides the math that transform from the x y theta velocities to the velocities on each of the motors that you have.

The equations are for each configuration and depends also on the separation of the wheels, radius of the wheels and orientation of them and also if there is any gearbox or transmission mechanism.

If you need more specific information of the equations please provide a schematic of the wheel configuration.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I do need help with the equations. Their is no transmission mechanism. The car used is children car in which children of age 6-10 year old can sit. One motor controls the steering angle and other 4 motors are on each wheel(total 5 motors). Motors used are simple DC motors. The dimensions of the car are- Inner radius(wheel)-10 cm, Outer Radius-15 cm, distance between two wheels(from centre) are 85cm(length) and 65cm(breadth). Thank you.